# Numpy vectorized function assignment with a boolean statement

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I would like to assign a function that has a boolean evaluation in it, using a fast way. Here is a simple example. I want the following function to be evaluated for arbitrary `a` and `b`:

```
a = 0.5
b = 0.6
def func(x):
    x=max(x,a)
    if x>b:
        return x**2
    else:
        return x**3
```

and then I want to assign the function values into an array in a vectorized manner (for speed):

```
xRange = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
arr_func = func(xRange)
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Now, I know I can assign the values in a loop. But that will be slow compared to the vectorized equivalent. Can I bypass this exception and still assign the values in a vectorized manner?

Comment: I think you could use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Don't use `np.vectorize` here!

Comment: @Lukisn, you should consider deleting your comment since it got an upvote and is misleading, see your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713023/1628638).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, the vectorized version of this would be to use a couple `np.where`:

```
def func(x):
    x = np.where(a > x, a, x)
    return np.where(x > b, x**2, x**3)
```

Comment: @DanielF -- Yes, you're probably right.  However, that would modify the argument (`xRange` in the case of OP's example).  That may not be desirable.  Numpy is already making a bunch of copies in both cases -- the (frequently correct) assumption that is _usually_ made when writing numpy code is that the overhead of the copies is small compared to the overhead of python loops.

Comment: True - I'm surprised pass by reference doesn't trip me up more considering  how often I forget it :)  Deleted the comment to prevent confusion

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to use `np.select` - it's a little wordier than necessary in this case, but is extensible to many conditions

```
def func(x):
    condlist =   [
                  x < a, 
                  (x >= a) & (x <= b), 
                  x > b
                 ]
    choicelist = [
                  a**3, 
                  x**3, 
                  x**2
                 ]
    return np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

or

```
def func(x):
    condlist =   [
                  x < a,  
                  x > b
                 ]
    choicelist = [
                  a**3, 
                  x**2
                 ]
    return np.select(condlist, choicelist, default = x**3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want (or have) to keep your original function, you could use numpy's [vectorize function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to create the "vectorized" version that accepts a numpy array as an input.

Note that this function is only for convenience and offers **no performance improvements** since it internally only implements a for loop. So there is no "real" vectorization!

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, a=0.5, b=0.6):
    x = max(x, a)
    if x > b:
        return x**2
    else:
        return x**3

vfunc = np.vectorize(func)  # this is it!

xRange = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
arr_func = vfunc(xRange)

print(arr_func)
```

The above code works and produces the following output:

```
[ 0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.36   0.49   0.64   0.81 ]
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You may want to read the "Notes" section of the [`vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer to make this clear.